# Misplaced \omit with multicolumn and classicthesis.sty

Tags: multicolumn, classicthesis

I've read almost all postings concerning this omit thing with multicolumn. However, I don't know why it doesn't work for my very simple tabular. I always get the message:

> ```
> Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit \@multispan l.76 ...Beispiel 1} \multicolumn{2}{l}{Beispiel 2} \\
> ```

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    dottedtoc, 
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, 
    ngerman, 
    ]{scrreprt} 

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\myfloatalign
%\caption[test2]{test2}
\begin{tabular}[m]{m{1.5cm}m{3cm}m{1.5cm}m{3cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Beispiel 1} \multicolumn{2}{l}{Beispiel 2}\\
\includegraphics{examplepicture} & Dr. Siegfried Hosenkötter    &  \includegraphics{examplepicture2} & Dr. Ilse Hosenkötter \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SX. Could you provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe), starting with `\documentclass..` and ending with `\end{document}` (including the `usepackage` list etc.? What does the user-defined macro `\myfloatalign` do?

Comment: There is no proper markup. Are there double backslash at the end 9f your lines?

Comment: Yes, there are double backslash at the ends.

Comment: Hello nox, thanks for your answer. I just use classicthesis.sty and the myfloatalign is included in the overall setup of the package. I don't know what it is doing exactly, but if I take it out, the tabular gives the same message. If I take the multicolumn thing away, it is working.

Comment: I don't know where I can write the code to make it look as it looks in Latex? Sorry!

Comment: You can use the edit button on the bottom left of your question `;)` see my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `&`s to separate the multicol cells helps `;)`. This code works for me (I changed the dimension of the table, though, and don't load the classic thesis config here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%\myfloatalign
%\caption[test2]{test2}
\begin{tabular}[m]{m{1.5cm}m{4cm}m{1.5cm}m{4cm}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Beispiel 1}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{Beispiel 2}\\
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-10x16} & Dr. Siegfried Hosenkötter &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-10x16} & Dr. Ilse Hosenkötter
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much, nox! I'm quite sure I already tried it with an & (although I've read in documentation that it's not necessary), however... doesn't matter. I'm happy :). Thanks again and have a great day.

Comment: No worries, that's what we're here for `:-)` Before you leave the site, consider accepting the answer if it helped you, so others don't see this question as unanswered.